# why is this rsync command not deleteing?

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

Can anyone please tell me why this rsync command doesn't delete?

It just keeps adding new files, but never deleting files on the destination that are no longer on the source.

rsync -avz -e --delete --rsh='ssh -p1157' /backup/virtualservers/monthly/ [removed for security]:/volume1/NetBackup/virtalservers/monthly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the -e argument is the same as the --rsh according to the man page

-e, --rsh=COMMAND
This  option  allows  you  to  choose an alternative remote shell program to use for communication between the local and remote copies of rsync.  Typically,  rsync  is configured  to  use  ssh  by default, but you may prefer to use rsh on a local network.

so I think your command is confusing, try the following instead:

rsync -avz --delete --rsh='ssh -p1157' /backup/virtualservers/monthly/ [removed for security]:/volume1/NetBackup/virtalservers/monthly

Romain